# Loading SDK component information failed in Android SDK Manager, Android SDK Instance could not be loaded in Android Device Manager

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, android-sdk-manager, android-device-manager

for this project I am using VS 2017. I want to note that everything in Android SDK Manager and in Android Device Manager has always been working fine for me, but today my laptop's account password was expiring, so I changed it, and right after that I started having a lot of issues with VS (I thought maybe this was important to note).
So, when opening Android SDK Manager, I am suddenly seeing this:
[image]

And the solution to navigate to the gear icon and change the Repository to "Google" doesn't help me, in fact, it was already set to Google (I tried setting it to Microsoft, closing the manager, and then resetting to Google, didn't work).
Retrying doesn't help.
Does anyone know what to do? I am really stuck at this point, I tried restarting my PC and restarting VS, and in regards to my problem I also tried signing out and signing back in VS just in case, but it also didn't work. Any help much appreciated

Edit:
I also tried actually setting the SDK Location in SDK Manager, but that didn't work:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps this is a good opportunity to upgrade to VS 2019 or 2022. [Xamarin.Forms 5 drops VS 2017 support](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2021/01/07/xamarin-forms-5.aspx). Otherwise, you're in an environment that few people are using for Xamarin; hard to get help when VS problems like this happen.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I actually have both VS2017 and VS2019, and in 2019 I have the same issue right now :c

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio for Mac and actually having the same issue since a few days (on two different machines). Seems like an issue on "their" side.

Comment: Having the same problem suddenly. Seems like a VS bug

Comment: you could report your issue here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?port=1025&fsid=05d23598-4e69-4682-bad3-60fdafd582fb&entry=problem

Comment: I have this issue too with MS Visual Studio 2019. The Android SDK refuses to load/update and displays exactly as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Switching the source to the approved list helped for me.
Leaving out the latest versions, but at least works...
->Click on the gear and select